# iOS 6 iPhone app crashes on iPad with iOS 7

Tags: ipad, ios7

I have released an app built on Xcode 4.6.3 with following settings:

[image: Xcode 4.6.3 iOS app target]

[image]

- It works well on iPhone iOS 6 and iOS 7. It also works well on iPad
  with iOS 6.
- On iPad with iOS 7 it crashes on launch.

Many of our customers use this iPhone app on their iPad. What settings should I change to get it working?

Crash Report:
[image]

Comment: what about the crash report????

Comment: Any error message? Can you debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As Crash Logs mentioned crash was due to "substringWithRange" but I could not get exact location in code. So my friend suggestion worked. I had to enable all exception to catch the exact location of crash.
To enable it:

**1: Click Breakpoint Navigator in xcode**

[image]

2: **Locate '+' symbol at bottom left. Then Select "Add Exception Breakpoint" and re-run app in debug mode. It should halt at exact location where it crashed.**

[image]

Due to this I found exact location of problem. It's happening only for iPad with iOS 7 because of some lib giving me incomplete string for iPad iOS 7 i.e. DeviceModel value not displaying.